# Run ruby code at execution (run time) time

Tags: chef-infra

Here is the code, I want to execute it at converge time to get the variable value on run time:

**attribute/default.rb**:

```
default['dir_list'] = []
```

recipes/defailt.rb

```
node['dir_list'].each do |dir|
  directory dir.to_s do
    group 'root'
    owner 'root'
    mode '755'
    recursive true
    action :create
  end
end
```

**recipes/list_dir.rb**:

```
node.default['dir_list'] = ['/usr/dir1', '/usr/dir2', /usr/dir3']
```

**run_list**:

- recipes[list_dir]
- recipes[default]

Here the first recipe list_dir.rb, sets the variable with 3 directories that will be created by default.rb.

The issue is here, the default.rb is not setting these directories as the values are taken at the time of compilation.

Is there anyway, we can set the node['dir_list'] at the run time and execute the code on default.rb.

Here I am trying to create a multiple of directories dynamically by providing the directory list at the time of run time. So, Please advise the best way to call the directory resource at the run time.

Comment: I should be working as you described. Make sure that `list_dir` recipe is called before the `default`. If not you always can include `list_dir` recipe in `default` using `include_recipe`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway, we can set the node['dir_list'] at the run time

sure you can, here is an excert from [chef documenation](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#recipes)

> An attribute can be defined in a cookbook (or a recipe) and then used to override the default settings on a node. When a cookbook is loaded during a Chef Infra Client run, these attributes are compared to the attributes that are already present on the node. Attributes that are defined in attribute files are first loaded according to cookbook order. For each cookbook, attributes in the default.rb file are loaded first, and then additional attribute files (if present) are loaded in lexical sort order. When the cookbook attributes take precedence over the default attributes, Chef Infra Client applies those new settings and values during a Chef Infra Client run on the node.

you can set\change a node attribute in your recipe by using one of the [attribute types](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#attribute-types). see [change attributes](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#change-attributes) for more information.

as an example, default attribute in node object in recipe:

```
node.default['apache']['dir'] = '/etc/apache2'
```

few notes:

1. make sure that the recipe that sets the node attribute(s) appears before any other recipe(s) that reads the node attribute (i see that you mentioned the run-list order)
2. setting a node attribute in a recipe is usually done because of the value is only known at chef-client convergance phase. if that is not the case, consider moving the node attribute to an attribute file.